# TMaskEdit shrinking width issue in Delphi 7 IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I noticed a strange behavior about the VCL's `TMaskEdit` component.

When you change the `EditMask` property's value at design-time, the control's `Width` reduces by 1 pixel.

Easy to reproduce, drop a `TMaskEdit` on a Form at design-time and change the `EditMask` value in the Object Inspector. I repeatedly changed the value to `'9'` and `'0'` until the `Width` went to zero.

The problem does not exist at runtime.

Is it a known problem, and is there a solution? I have a `TCustomMaskEdit` descendant component and I would love to get rid of this issue.

**update:**
after some investigation I found the problematic code here: `TCustomMaskEdit.SetCursor`.

This is where the "magic" happens:

```
for I := Low(NewKeyState) to High(NewKeyState) do
  NewKeyState[I] := 0;
NewKeyState [VK_SHIFT] := $81;
NewKeyState [ArrowKey[UseRightToLeftAlignment]] := $81;
SetKeyboardState(NewKeyState);
FSettingCursor := True;
try
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, ArrowKey[UseRightToLeftAlignment], 1);
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_KEYUP, ArrowKey[UseRightToLeftAlignment], 1);
finally
  FSettingCursor := False;
end;
```

As much as I understand it emulates SHIFT + LEFT, but in design-time it will be handled by the IDE, this causes the control resize.

As a workaround solution I changed my component's ancestor to `TCustomMaskEdit`, haven't published the `EditMask` property, and in the code where this property changes I save and restore the `Width`. Not a nice way, but unfortunately the `SetCursor` is not virtual, so I can't override to do nothing in design-time.

Comment: I can confirm that this still happens in Delphi 2007. I'm also surprised to see it still exists in 10.4 with all patches applied. It gets worse if you use the EditMask property editor - it reduces by 2 instead of 1 (at least in D2007).

Comment: Well I don't think there will be an update for Delphi 7 any time soon, so why not alter the code in the VCL. You already found where the problem is.

Comment: Good idea. To be honest I never ever modified anything in the VCL, dont even know how to do that properly, but I will have a look, thanks.

Comment: @tcxbalage: Just create a new control with the same source code as the `TMaskEdit` but with your bug fix applied.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.